# Android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, runtime-error, classcastexception

I'm trying to get the instance of a ImageView defined in an XML layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/visual_compass_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/output_container" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/visual_compass"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="Compass"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/compass_rose" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But I always get that runtime error:

```
... java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be
cast to android.widget.ImageView ... at net.example.MainActivity.onCreate
(MainActivity.java:57)
```

Line "57" is that one:

```
compassView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.visual_compass);
```

I can't figure out why that error ist thrown; I don't see the problem with that piece of code. Does anybody elso know?

Thank you, Felix D.

Comment: have you tried to clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I'm working with Eclipse: so should i create a new peoject and copy all modified files from the old ont to it?

Comment: no, there is an option in Eclipse - clean, it would delete all generated files and then you have to build again, which will regenerate them. (Project -> Clean, if you didn't know)

Comment: Are you sure, that you didn't accidentally write `RelativeLayout compassView;`[...]? If not, then cleaning the project will probably help like others already suggested.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your quick comments. I'll try cleaning the project. And post my results here. @Ahmad And yes, I'm sure.

Comment: Post your whole activity code and try add : ImageView compassView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.visual_compass);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure in your code the `compassView` is `ImageView` variable only and try to access it as

```
  ImageView compassView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.visual_compass);
```

And if everything is correct then try to clean and Build your project again from the menu `Project-> clean.` and `Proejct-> Build`.

Comment: OK! that helped. Tahnk you. But I think the Project is rebuild automatically after being cleaned. And Eclipse automatically checks wether the cast ist correct...